# Write local files using skulpt

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there any tutorial out there on using "skulpt" and local SQlite (client side).
Using skulpt, I want to be able to create, write, open, modify local files.
Few years ago, I wrote a small browser-based app for my personal use using sqlite and javascript. The problem I faced is that javascript does not allow to access local files, write files, etc...I hope to be able to go around this limitation using skulpt.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) actually uses 100% Javascript under the hood, so you have *exactly* the same limitations in Skulpt as in regular Javascript.